# Compilation error: cannot convert argument 1 from 'student[20]' to 'student'

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I wrote part of a code that is supposed to take in a datafile and place the data into an array of structures. I have gotten the data to go into their respective places but im having trouble finding a way to determine amount of students in the file. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct student{
   string fname, lname, id, classname[20];
   char grade[20];
   int units[20], unitstaken, unitscompleted, numberofclasses;
   float gpa, points[20], avg;
};

void doesitrun(ifstream& fin, string& filename);
void readit(student& temp, ifstream& fin);
int Read_List(student child, int size);

int main(){
   int i = 0, size = 0;
   ifstream fin;
   string filename;
   student u[20];
   doesitrun(fin, filename);
   size = Read_List(u[20], 20);

   for (i; i < 3; i++){
      readit(u[i], fin);
   }



   cout << size << endl;
   cout << u[2].classname[11];
   cout << u[2].grade[11] << endl;

}

void doesitrun(ifstream& fin, string& filename){
   bool trueorfalse;
   cout << "Enter file name along with location: ";
   getline(cin, filename);
   cin.ignore(20, '\n');
   fin.open(filename.c_str());
   if (fin.fail())
      trueorfalse = false;
   else
      trueorfalse = true;
   while (trueorfalse == false){
      cout << "File does not run. Please try again. " << endl;
      fin.close();
      cout << "Enter file name along with location: ";      

      getline(cin, filename);
      fin.open(filename.c_str());
      if (fin.fail())
         trueorfalse = false;
      else
         trueorfalse = true;
   }

}

void readit(student& temp, ifstream& fin){

   int i = 0;
   getline(fin, temp.lname, ',');
   cin.ignore();
   getline(fin, temp.fname);
   fin >> temp.id;
   fin >> temp.numberofclasses;
   fin.ignore(10, '\n');

   for (i = 0; i < temp.numberofclasses; i++){

      getline(fin, temp.classname[i]);
      fin >> temp.grade[i];
      fin >> temp.units[i];
      fin.ignore(10, '\n');
   }

}


int Read_List(student child, int size)
{
   ifstream fin;
   int      i = 0;

   readit(child, fin);
   while (!fin.eof())
   {
      i++;
      if (i >= size)
      {
         cout << "Array is full.\n";
         break;
      }
      readit(child, fin);
   }
   fin.close();
   return i;
}
```

this is an example of a data file i would use:

```
Smith Jr., Joe
111-22-3333 3
Physics I
A 5
English 1A
B 4
English 1B
F 4
Jones, Bill 
111-11-1111 4
Physics I
A 5
Chemistry 1A
B 5
Computer Science 1
A 4
Chemistry 1 Lab
B 1
Brown, Nancy
222-11-1111 13
Physics I
A 5
English 1A
B 4
English 1B
F 4
Physics II
A 5
Chemistry 1A
B 5
Computer Science 1
A 4
Chemistry 1A Lab
B 1
Physics I Lab
A 1
Physics II Lab
A 1
Physics III
A 5
Physics III Lab
A 1
Chemistry 1B
A 5
Chemistry 1B Lab
A 1
```

I want to edit my code so that i can get the Read_List function to find me the number of students in the file. In this example, size would come out to be 3.

Comment: `u[20]` is just an out-of-bounds element.

Comment: what should i change it to? u[i]? u[]? u?

Comment: `student u[20]`; creates an array with **20** elements, which can be accessed by indexes **0-19**.

Comment: There are quite a few problems in your code. I think it will be better for you to start with a smaller program. Get it work before adding more functionality to it.

Comment: @Ammar, `u` if you're trying to pass the whole thing, but it's hard to say here.

Comment: @chris if i leave it 'u' the compiler says  "no suitable constructor exists to convert for 'student[20]' to 'student'".

Comment: @RSahu from what i've tested, asides from giving me the amount of students in a file, my code does all i want it to do at the moment, which is take data from a file and place it into an array of structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure the purpose of the code `size = Read_List(u[20], 20);` in the example, but the part `u[20]` where "20" is an index of the location of array of "u" variable. Therefore, the index cannot exceed the size of the array which means "20" in `u[20]` must be less than 20 (eg. 19).

And the parameter passing u[i] to the function `readit(student& temp, ifstream& fin)`must be an address of the pointer (or array) but the call `readit()` appears to pass the value of the pointer.

Comment: Ive changed it to 19, i, [], and nothing but none of them give me the number 3, which is what i want. Is it maybe a problem with my Read_List function?

Comment: @Ammar You probably need to declare a pointer to the base address of struct (eg student *stnt; stnt = new student[10] and then call size = Read_List(stnt,20). You will also need to modify the function Read_List() to take an address to the pointer of the struct rather than the struct. Hope this helps.